Why is the For loop only iterating once?
I need to take this information in StudentInfo.tsv:
Barrett    Edan    70  45  59

Bradshaw    Reagan  96  97  88
Charlton    Caius   73  94  80
Mayo    Tyrese  88  61  36
Stern    Brenda  90  86  45

and make it output to another file like this:
Barrett    Edan    70  45  59  F
Bradshaw    Reagan  96  97  88  A
Charlton    Caius   73  94  80  B
Mayo    Tyrese  88  61  36  D
Stern    Brenda  90  86  45  C

Averages: midterm1 83.40, midterm2 76.60, final 61.60

This is what I have up to the point of rewriting the Student information and adding the letter grade. However, the for loop is not functioning the way I need it to.
The output I get is '[]'
import csv

def calculate_grade(average_score):
  if average_score >= 90:
      return 'A'
  elif 80 <= average_score < 90:
      return 'B'
  elif 70 <= average_score < 80:
      return 'C'
  elif 60 <= average_score < 70:
      return 'D'
  else:
      return 'F'

tsv_input = str(input())
student_data = []


with open(tsv_input) as file_a:
    tsv_read = file_a.readlines()
    
    for row in tsv_read:
        student_data = [row.strip().split('\t')]

with open('report.txt', 'a+') as final_file:
    for info in student_data:
        last_name, first_name, midterm1, midterm2, final = info
        average_score = (float(midterm1) + float(midterm2) + float(final)) / 3
        
        final_grade = calculate_grade(average_score)
        
        final_file.write(f'{last_name}\t{first_name}\t{midterm1}\t{midterm2}\t{final}\{final_grade}\n')
    final_read = final_file.readlines()
    print(final_read)


It looks like the bug lines in how you populate your student_data

I changed to line to update student data to <for row in tsv_read:
student_data.append(row.strip().split('\t'))>  and verified that student data now comes out correctly, but the final output is till []

I suspect its something to do with how the file is formatted, such that the tabs are not recognized properly. Is it possible to use CSV instead?

If the 2nd line of the data file is empty you have to manage this special case in the for loop like testing the length of the data retrieved from the file

How are you generating the final averages output?

Change the line:
student_data = [row.strip().split('\t')]

to:
student_data.append(row.strip().split("\t"))

You don't want to assign student_data to something new but instead append splitted lines to it.

Your code has three issues:

As noted by yourself in the comments, and in the answer by @S.B, you are overwriting student_data each time with the input from the last line instead of adding it using list.append:

student_data = []

with open(tsv_input) as file_a:
    tsv_read = file_a.readlines()
    
    for row in tsv_read:
        # Issue 1: use: `list.append`
        # student_data = [row.strip().split('\t')]
        student_data.append(row.strip().split('\t'))


(minor) You have a typo in final_file.write(...):

        # Issue 2 (typo)
        # change `\{final_grade}` -> `\t{final_grade}`
        final_file.write(f'{last_name}\t{first_name}\t{midterm1}\t{midterm2}\t{final}\t{final_grade}\n')


final_file.readlines() returns an empty list. This is a misunderstanding on what it means to use open in mode a+. From the BSD fopen manpage under a+ (cf. here):


Open for reading and writing. The file is created if it does not exist. The stream is positioned at the end of the file. [italics added]

I.e., when you call f.readlines, the file's cursor is at the end of the file, naturally leading to an empty list: there is nothing there.
For the desired result, you will first need to return to the start of the file. You can use f.seek for this:
    # Issue 3 (reset cursor to start file, i.e. `0`)
    final_file.seek(0)
    final_read = final_file.readlines()
    print(final_read)

print
['Barrett\tEdan\t70\t45\t59\tF\n', 
 'Bradshaw\tReagan\t96\t97\t88\tA\n', 
 'Charlton\tCaius\t73\t94\t80\tB\n', 
 'Mayo\tTyrese\t88\t61\t36\tD\n', 
 'Stern\tBrenda\t90\t86\t45\tC\n']


In order for you to produce the final averages you'll need to keep running totals. You also need to account for the empty line in your input. Each line must have exactly 5 tokens.
INFILE = "foo.tsv"
OUTFILE = "report.txt"

grade_map = {
    90: "A",
    80: "B",
    70: "C",
    60: "D"
}

def calculate_grade(n):
    for k, v in grade_map.items():
        if n >= k:
            return v
    return "F"


totals = [0, 0, 0]
n = 0

with open(INFILE) as data, open(OUTFILE, "w") as output:
    for line in data:
        tokens = line.split()
        if len(tokens) == 5: # sanity check
            n += 1
            values = list(map(int, tokens[2:]))
            for i, v in enumerate(values):
                totals[i] += v
            tokens.append(calculate_grade(sum(values) / len(values)))
            print(" ".join(tokens), file=output)

    averages = [total / n for total in totals]

    print(f"Averages: midterm1 {averages[0]:.2f}, midterm2 {averages[1]:.2f}, final {averages[2]:.2f}", file=output)

